Accessing imported modules in jest
I am using this format to import modules in a ts project.
import { Configs } from '@configs'

Based on using this setting in tsconfig.json
    "paths": {
      "@configs": ["configs"],
    }

And this in jest.config.js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@configs/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/configs/$1"
    }

And this is the error I get when running tests
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@configs'

         > 16 | import { Configs } from '@configs'
         | ^


https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/

@DanielA.White thank you. That is the doc I used for "^@configs/(.*)$": "/configs/$1"
Still not sure what I am missing.

Your import doesn’t have the slash but the regex expects it

Typo with use of sub directory /
